# Not able to get top 1 in power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-mobile

- Customer table

  contains the column "Status","created_date","updated date"
- ascs table

  contains the column "service_station_name"

First I add new measure for "status count" by using following eqn:

```
    Status Count = COUNT('cps customers'[status])
```

then  a new column for "day duration" by using following eqn:

```
     Day Duration2 = SWITCH('cps 
     customers'[status],"Closed",DATEDIFF('cps customers'[created_at], 
    [updated_at],DAY),"Unattended",DATEDIFF('cps 
    customers'[created_at],NOW(),DAY),"Assigned",DATEDIFF('cps 
    customers'[created_at],NOW(),DAY),"NotApplicable",DATEDIFF('cps 
    customers'[created_at],NOW(),DAY),"Open",DATEDIFF('cps 
    customers'[created_at],NOW(),DAY))
```

I need **top service station name**.. 
Conditions:

```
    i.   Consider only **closed status**
    ii.  Top count of **closed status count**
    iii. Lowest **time duration**
```

Steps:

1. Select columns **service_station_name**,**status**,**status count** and **day duration2**
   [image]
2. Filter the closed status from column "status".
   [image]
3. Add TOPN filteration for "status count" 
   [image]

   Now, I got three service_station_name where each have 5 closed status count.
4. And for getting the lowest "day duration2" I used ascending order 
   [image]"
5. And for displaying the top 1 service_station_name, I chosen the **CARD** from 
   visualization and get **First service_station_name**.Bt I haven't got the 
   proper answer
   [image]
6. Then I took **last service_station_name** . Here also i haven't got the 
   answer.[image]

Based on the screenshot, I need "Om Sakthi Engineering" as answer.
How I get the answer? Can anybody help me!

Comment: Is there any way  to get  the answer by using "new measure" or "new column"...

Answer (score 0):

You could actually add in another column "NewColumn", then the value would be the "Status Count" divided by "day Duration". The highest value will be the top one.

```
NewColumn = divide(Table1[Status Count],Table1[Day Duration])
```

Then you can use card visualization to pick the top one value. 
Under filters, you should filter status as closed, filter the top 1 for this NewColumn.
[image]

Comment: I tried, but not able find an answer. Can u give some more explanation.